# Google App Engine error when use opencensus ext

Tags: google-app-engine, php-7.3, opencensus

```
WARNING: [pool app] child 29 said into stderr: "php-fpm: pool app: symbol lookup error: /opt/php73/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/opencensus.so: undefined symbol: ZVAL_DESTRUCTOR"
```

I using GAE env flex. today GAE use php7.3-fpm and i got that error. I check other website in GAE using php7.2-fpm working normally.

How can i fix problem.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow, are you using app engine flex or standard? could you share the your app.yaml file?

Comment: Im use GAE flex. This is my app.yaml

Comment: Today website working normally. but after 4pm website die. im debug saw difference php version. im used extensions opencensus for tracing

Comment: Check the tutorial for titling a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your app.yaml you should set the runtime:

```
env: flex
runtime: php
```

On your `composer.json` file you should specify the version that you want to use, for example if you want to use php 7.2 instead of 7.3:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": "7.2.*"
    }
}
```

It's important to specify said version otherwise the runtime might upgrade inadvertently into a new version as mentioned in the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime#choosing_a_php_version)

> By default, the PHP runtime uses PHP 7.2, but you should explicitly
> declare your PHP version in the composer.json file to prevent your
> application from being automatically upgraded when a new version of
> PHP becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

````
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 1
  disk_size_gb: 10
runtime_config:
  document_root: public

# Ensure we skip ".env", which is only for local development
skip_files:
  - .env
  - .git
  - /vendor/
  - /node_modules/

env_variables:
  # Put production environment variables here.
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  APP_KEY: **App_Key**
  APP_NAME: Application
  APP_ENV: production
  APP_DEBUG: true ```
````

Comment: Try to edit your question and include all the information there, remove the APP_KEY (which seems like an authentication API Key) and remove the answer posted by you with the app.yaml